# Como implementar um alert na pagina HTML no angular?

Tags: angular

Como vocês podem ver na figura abaixo o componente Angular é composto de componente, css e HTMl

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no **arquivo midia-cadastrar.component.html** tentei colocar uma implementação simples de alert como você pode ver abaixo;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("alo tudo bem?");
  </script>
```

Sendo que não pegou, mas se eu colocar no arquivo index.html que fica na raiz do projeto ele pega perfeitamente.

Eu quero conseguir implementar o alert na pagina **arquivo midia-cadastrar.component.html**, como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara o mais indicado em aplicações Angular é vc colocar todo código `javascript (typescript)` no **midia-cadastrar.component.ts** é para isso que ele serve, o HTML é só para apresentação:

> HTML

```
<button (click)="botaoClicado()">Clique</button>
```

> JS - Vc cria um método para disparar o alert no click do botão

```
export class midiaCadastrarComponent implements OnInit {
    botaoClicado() {
       alert('Botão clicado!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No arquivo midia-cadastrar.component.html tenta fazer isso..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Button" onclick="alerta()"/>

<script>
function alerta(){
 alert("alo tudo bem?");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```